# Cannot perform SQL injection because of the weird postgresql syntax that is used

Tags: sql-injection, postgresql

I have a website that uses ManageEngine Service Plus and it has a [SQL injection vulnerability](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/35890)

the linksays that with the help of the following url we would be able to inject postgresql commands to get the complete control of the system:

```
/reports/CreateReportTable.jsp?site=0 AND
3133=(SELECT 3133 FROM PG_SLEEP(1))
```

I don't understand the part `3133=(SELECT 3133 FROM PG_SLEEP(1))`. I know the databse is Postgresql but when I try to find an appropriate injection command on PayloadsAllTheThings or other sites I cannot anything in that format.

Can you give me tips on how to dump table names or so since it doesn't seem to execute any function other than `pg_sleep()`?

Comment: The part between parentheses is a [subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES).

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can get the version using that subquery?

Comment: What makes you think that the SQL Injection attack isn't working?  Do you get an error when you use the example URL?

Comment: SQLi works perfectly, the sleep function does the work it is supposed to do. I just cannot type exact query to get the table of credentials since it is postgresql and I already searched about subquries but it still doesn't ring a bell. Could you please write that exact query so I could understand it. What gets me most confused is the 3133= before the subquery.

Comment: All it is doing is creating a true condition of 3133=3133 in the Where clause and proving that you can inject other SQL queries into the querystring, which is a SQL Injection vunerability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Attack type**

`0 AND 3133=(SELECT 3133 FROM PG_SLEEP(1))`

is a method of [blind sql injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Blind_SQL_Injection). Blind sqli applies time to determine the content of the database, mostly using if conditions (cf eg [SQL Injection Cheat Sheet - Conditional Time Delays](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/cheat-sheet)). So if you are interested in using this technique for dumping explore it for postgreSQL.

`3133` is a fixed value and `PG_SLEEP(1)` delays the execution at the database for 1 second. So basically this sums up to `0 AND true` with a waiting time of 1 second.
You can use this to check if this type of sqli is feasible.

Basically the referenced [exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/35890) is a proof-of-concept to show that sql injection is possible.

It is also listed as [CVE](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2015-1479).

**How does it work?**

I don't know what `CreateReportTable.jsp` does exactly. I only found this [documentation](https://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk-msp/help/adminguide/reports/custom-reports.html). The documentation mentions:

> To use Advanced Filtering, select the column name such as, Requester
> name, **region site** and so on from the combo box.

which probably belongs to a filtering of [sites/branches](https://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk-msp/help/adminguide/configurations/helpdesk/configuring-sites.html) you can define for your company. So this could be an entry point to check where the issue is in your application. Analyse the query parameter `site`.

If you want a deeper understanding what `SELECT 3133 FROM PG_SLEEP(1)` does you can verify it using docker:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_DB=db -d postgres:latest 

sudo docker exec -ti <your_docker_container_id> psql "dbname=db user=user password=mysecretpassword"
```

`psql` is the interactive terminal for postgres. In this terminal `\dt` gives you an overview about what the function `pg_sleep` does.
The function has a return data type of `void` - which is basically an empty value. Enter `select * from pg_sleep(1)` to double check that. This will bring you back after one second and outputs no value. At first the function is applied and then the select is executed.
The empty return value then can be overwritten by choosing a constant:

```
select 1 from pg_sleep(1);
```

[image: psql example]

**Mitigation possibilities and impact**

The [CVE](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2015-1479) states

> SQL injection vulnerability in reports/CreateReportTable.jsp in ZOHO
> ManageEngine ServiceDesk Plus (SDP) before **9.0 build 9031** allows
> remote authenticated users to execute arbitrary SQL commands via the
> site parameter.

So probably it is fixed with an update to a higher version.

The other thing is that you have to consider a possible breach depending if and how long your site has been exposed.